# Передать параметры в класс-обработчик из слота

Tags: c++, qt, ооп

Приложение Qt Widget. Есть окно, главные элементы на котором это QLineEdit и QTreeWidget.

Перед запуском приложения происходит парсинг XML-файла и формирование структуры данных в виде контейнера QHash. За парсинг отвечает класс Parser и хранит контейнер, доступ к нему извне  через метод чтения организован.

После ввода ключа в строку нужно запустить поиск по контейнеру в Parser и сформировать в QTreeWidget данные. За поиск и формирование данных отвечает класс Search.

Как в стиле ООП правильно вызвать в слоте on_lineEdit_returnPressed  метод класса Search, отвечающий за поиск?
Сейчас я для этого ввел в класс Search поле с указателем на Parser и в MainWindow поле с указателем на Search. Эти указатели инициализирую в конструкторе.

Оно работает, но мне кажется есть другой способ более правильный.

```
class Search : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Search(Parser *pp, QWidget *parent = 0);
    ....
private:
    Parser *pParser;
};

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT    
public:
    explicit MainWindow(Search *pse, QWidget *parent = 0);
private slots:
    void on_lineEdit_in_returnPressed();
    ....
private:    
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;  
    Search *pSearch;
}
```

Реализация:

```
void MainWindow::on_lineEdit_in_returnPressed()
{
    pSearch->searchId(ui->treeWidget_in, ui->treeWidget_out, ui->lineEdit_in);  
}
```

main.cpp:

```
void main (){
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    Parser *pr = new Parser();
    pr->initKeyName();
    Search *se = new Search(pr);

    MainWindow w(se);
    w.show();
}
```

Comment: Здесь, конечно, жесткая жесть 1. `pSearch->searchId(ui->treeWidget_in, ui->treeWidget_out, ui->lineEdit_in);` 2. Непонятно зачем наследовать Search от QWidget ... Но, это уже чистая археология. Культурные слои прошлого )